# Qt strange debugger error QWidget and QApplication

Tags: c++, qt

This happens when i enter the code to the slots of my buttons

[image]

when i debug the app normally ,all functions etc everything is ok. 
but when i try use my code in UI something brokes down.
I'm making the Parking System for my uni classes ,
i got one parent class vehicle and 4 child classes which inherits by public.

here's the code from the UI source file :

```
#include "datain.h"
#include "ui_datain.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <car.h>
#include <bike.h>
#include <motorbike.h>
#include <tir.h>
#include <vehicle.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

dataIn::dataIn(QWidget *parent) :
     QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::dataIn)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

dataIn::~dataIn()
    {
    delete ui;
    }
 dataIn siema;


 void dataIn::on_lineEdit_textEdited(const QString &arg1)
{
   siema.rejestracja=arg1;
 }

void dataIn::on_lineEdit_2_textEdited(const QString &arg1)
{
    siema.marka=arg1;
}

 void dataIn::on_car_clicked()
{
    Vehicle *wsk;

    string reje,mareczka;
    reje=siema.rejestracja.toStdString();
    mareczka=siema.marka.toStdString();
    Car obj(reje,mareczka);

   wsk=&obj;
   wsk->add();

}

void dataIn::on_motorcycle_clicked()
{
    Vehicle *wsk;

    string reje,mareczka;
    reje=siema.rejestracja.toStdString();
    mareczka=siema.marka.toStdString();
    Motorbike obj(reje,mareczka);

  wsk=&obj;
  wsk->add();

}

void dataIn::on_bike_clicked()
{
    Vehicle *wsk;

string reje,mareczka;
reje=siema.rejestracja.toStdString();
mareczka=siema.marka.toStdString();
Bike obj(reje,mareczka);

wsk=&obj;
wsk->add();

}

 void dataIn::on_tir_clicked()
{
   Vehicle *wsk;

string reje,mareczka;
reje=siema.rejestracja.toStdString();
mareczka=siema.marka.toStdString();
Tir obj(reje,mareczka);

wsk=&obj;
wsk->add();

}
```

Here's the main:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

dataIn code:

```
#ifndef DATAIN_H
#define DATAIN_H
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDialog>
 using namespace std;
 namespace Ui {
class dataIn;
}

class dataIn : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
   QString rejestracja;
    QString marka;
public:
    explicit dataIn(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~dataIn();

private slots:

    void on_lineEdit_textEdited(const QString &arg1);

    void on_lineEdit_2_textEdited(const QString &arg1);

    void on_car_clicked();

    void on_motorcycle_clicked();

    void on_bike_clicked();

    void on_tir_clicked();

private:
    Ui::dataIn *ui;
};

#endif // DATAIN_H
```

Comment: Show your `main()`

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, but it's hard to say exactly what's wrong with your code since you didn't include the part that sets up the `QApplication` (assuming there is one.) Normally that would be in the `main` function but it doesn't have to.

Comment: thats the code of main.cpp
`#include "mainwindow.h
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

   return a.exec();
}`
@MrEricSir

Comment: @dresscherjm i've just edited the post

Comment: Is your dataIn object a static?

Comment: yes , as you can see i didn't use "*" if you say about this

Comment: Your `dataIn` object needs to be created after `QApplication a(argc, argv);` is executed.

Comment: when i declared it before dataIn object it showed the error:
argc,argv undefined identifier

Comment: That is because you moved it out of main.

Comment: so what should i do in main ? 
sorry i'm newbie ;(

Comment: My advice is to reconsider the static. Instead make your `dataIn` object a member of your MainWindow.

Comment: dataIn is yhe window wich is opened when the button in mainwindow is pressed. i don't nknow how to make dataIn object a member of mainwindow. Inheritance ?

Comment: dataIn is a dialog window

Comment: ***i don't nknow how to make dataIn object a member of mainwindow. Inheritance*** Not inheritance. Composition.

Comment: i don't know what are you talking about but i will research it, TY for now if i will have problem i wil write about it . thanks a lot

Comment: _something brokes down_ is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You may not declare

```
dataIn siema;
```

and you should not refer to it - remove all `siema.`... references from your dataIn functions (replace `siema.` with nothing or with `this->`).

When you need your dialog for the first time, create it in (and as child of) `MainWindow`:

```
void MainWindow::whateverEvent() {
    dataIn *siema = new dataIn(this);
    siema->show();
}
```

If you need to reference it again or want do prevent it from being created twice, store the pointer in a member of your `MainWindow`.